# Custom less-loader in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix, less-loader

I am trying to import LESS file in my JS code.
But I get error like - '*You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.*'. 
**Version - "laravel-mix": "^0.11.4"**

*In my webpack.mix.js I tried this code*

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ['style-loader','css-loader','less-loader']
        }]
    }
})........
```

But I still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#less. You do not have to configure anything special for LESS.

Comment: @RuChernChong thx for reply, I am using React so i need import style file in my Component, so this solution doesn't work laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#less. I use this
 `module: {
          rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader",
                   exclude: [
                       path.resolve(__dirname, "node-modules"),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/less"),
                   ],
               },            ]
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');
mix.webpackConfig({
 module: {
   rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader",
        exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node-modules"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/less"),
        ],
      },
  ]} 
})
```

Works for my issue